# getting errors while building GTK project

Tags: codeblocks, gtk2

I am new to `GTK+`, and I am trying to create my first application in Code-Blocks. Every has been done but when I build my project I am getting these errors (given below in image).

**Errors:**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)